# ¿Por qué se repite el último número en su copia al dividir el slice original?

Tags: go

Soy un completo principiante en GO y probando diferentes cosas con slices me encuentro con esto que no puedo explicármelo:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    y := x
    fmt.Printf("x: %v \ty: %v\n", x, y)
    x = append(x[:2], x[3:]...)
    fmt.Printf("x: %v \ty: %v\n", x, y)
}
```

la salida es:

> x: [1 2 3 4 5]    y: [1 2 3 4 5]

> x: [1 2 4 5]  y: [1 2 4 5 5]

¿Por qué repite el "5" en la copia?

Answer (score 1):

Parte del problema es lo siguiente:

- Lo que te esta pasando es que como solo estas trabajando con un array, 'X' e 'Y' apuntan al mismo slice en memoria.
- Usando el append estas eliminando el elemento del array y la salida de X se convierte en un array de 4, pero el de 'Y' sigue apuntando al array original. Al modificar 'X' también modificaste 'Y' y esta rellenando ese valor porque se modificaron

eso lo podes resolver usando 'copy' de esta manera, creas a 'Y' usando la funcion 'make' con el largo de 'x' para que sean de igual tamaño, y 'copy' para que sea independiente del anterior,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    y := make([]int, len(x))
    copy(y, x)

    fmt.Printf("x: %v \ty: %v\n", x, y)

    x = append(x[:2], x[3:]...)
    fmt.Printf("x: %v \ty: %v\n", x, y)
}
```

te dejo un ejemplo > [ejemplo de código - Using copy](https://freshman.tech/snippets/go/copy-slices/)

Comment: aunque agradezco tu respuesta, mi duda no es como hacer una copia, simplemente es porque razon repite el ultimo numero (ultimos 2 si sacas 2 numeros). porque no un 0?

Comment: analizando tu respuesta se me ocurre pensar que aunque los 2 apunten a la misma direccion de memoria al sacar un valor de x solo se modifica su longitud, o sea, x sigue teniendo el 5 final ya que y lo tiene, solo que se enmascaro al cambiar su longitud

Comment: ah ya capte tu punto,

Tengo una hipótesis, en 'X' eliminaste el ítem '3' por lo cual ese espacio paso a ser usado por el '4', seguido venia el '5' y el valor de la ultima posición, en memoria para ese array, continuaba siendo '5' y es verdad ¿Por qué no fue un cero?.


Eso es propio de como se comporte el lenguaje para estos casos, como el valor en memoria de esa posición era 5 inicialmente, ese pude ser el motivo. Quizas otro tenga una mejor hipotesis

Comment: Es como dices, solo agregar que la longitud de x ahora es de 4 numeros y la de y sigue siendo de 5. la posicion 5 ya no es apuntada en x pero lo sigue siendo en y. Curioso comportamiento, a de ser asi en c c++ calculo